# GMap.Net WPF OnManipulationDelta Release build missing?

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, gmap.net

I'm teaching myself WPF and touch interfacing using the GMap.Net interface and I've run into a problem that completely baffles me.

The short of it, I have code that runs fine in debug build but as soon as I switch to Release, I have functions that cannot be found.  I'll plop some examples.

In the GMapControl.cs file I have a functions that override from the System.Windows.UIElement classes.

```
protected override void OnManipulationDelta(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnManipulationDelta(e);
}
```

Error   CS0115  'GMapControl.OnManipulationDelta(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs)': no suitable method found to override GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation    GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation\GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation\GMapControl.cs

I don't understand as this UIElement is Microsoft code which is being inherited from and is only an error in the Release Build, the debug version runs without issue?

I have a few other instances exactly like this one:

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ManipulationDeltaEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   CS0115  'GMapControl.OnManipulationCompleted(ManipulationCompletedEventArgs)': no suitable method found to override

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ManipulationCompletedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is there something obviously that I'm overlooking?

Cheers
Aaron

Comment: Check your project references. There must be `PresentationCore` when you select `Release` build.

Comment: In addition to what Vasily.sib said... what version of Visual Studio are you using? I seem to recall having this happen after an VS update and it was fixed in a later update from MS. See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/160594/migrating-from-vs2017-154-to-155-causes-cs026-the.html

Comment: Thanks Vasily.sib - you put me in the right direction.  I found out through inspection that the PresentationCore was loading v3 of .NET and after trying to override it for far too long I eventually realised the Release build was building in 3.5 not 4 like the debug version.